# ! Unable to determine the platform for the `Yapping` target. -- Error message I received when trying to install/update pods (cocoa pods) in terminal

Tags: ios, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

target 'Yapping' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleMaps'

end

what im entering into my terminal and im getting the error code [!] Unable to determine the platform for the `FileName` target. Ive installed home-brew and ruby trying to fix this one issue but nothing had worked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.